# SQL max is non-deterministic?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables: cities and states. States has columns for state codes and full name. Cities contains columns for population, state code, and the city name. My goal is to create a table of the city in each state with the highest population.

This is my solution which seems to work in a test, but I've been told that using max() is non-deterministic and I should use a window function instead.

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    c.name,
    max(c.population)
FROM cities AS c 
LEFT JOIN states AS s
ON c.state_code = s.code
GROUP BY s.name
ORDER BY s.name;
```

What is wrong with using max here, when would it give incorrect results?

Comment: SELECT
    s.name,
    c.name,
    max(c.population)
FROM cities AS c 
LEFT JOIN states AS s
ON c.state_code = s.code
GROUP BY s.name,c.name
ORDER BY s.name;

Comment: need  c.name in group by

Comment: The issue here is using a scalar value, `c.name`, in a query with a group - if the column isn't in the group-by list or used with an aggregate function, sqlite picks a random row from the group to use for its value. Other databases raise an error.

Comment: I've fiddled with it in SQLite and can't seem to get incorrect city to occur. Is it  only non-deterministic in the case where multiple cities have the same population? And thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using - MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: The query is malformed since `c.name` is missing in the `GROUP BY` clause. Please fix the query first. Voting to close in the meantime. Even if it runs in some databases it's still malformed.

Comment: ^ Read the answer by @forpas. The query is not malformed in SQLite. Editing the query to remove `c.name` would make it impossible to ask the question I'm asking as the issue is in regard to SQLite's bare columns feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most databases your query would not even run, because you are selecting the non-aggregated column `c.name` without also using it in the `GROUP BY` clause.

For MySql, the code would run if [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode is disabled, but still it would return wrong results because the query would pick a random city name out of all the cities of each state.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=d67da6ab72ae859e88d9722e156df56d).

For SQLite, your query is **correct**!
SQLite's feature of [bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query), makes sure that the city name you get in the results is the one that has the max population.
This is non-standard, but it is documented.
The only problem here is that if there are 2 or more cities with the same max population you will get only one of them in the results.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d67da6ab72ae859e88d9722e156df56d).

Comment: There's a writeup of MySQL's notorious nonstandard GROUP BY handling [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: Thank you. Bare columns is exactly the feature I was trying to research re: aggregate functions in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the city in each state with the max population and use it in a sub-query and join it with the tables.

**Query**

```
select s.name as state, c.name as city, c.population
from states s
join cities c
on c.state_code = s.code
join (
  select state_code, max(population) as max_pop
  from cities 
  group by state_code
) as p
on p.state_code = c.state_code 
and p.max_pop = c.population;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 create table states(code varchar(50),name varchar(50));
 create table cities(code varchar(50),name varchar(50),population int, state_code varchar(50));

 insert into states values('s01','state1');

 insert into cities values('c01','city1',100,'s01');
 insert into cities values('c02','city2',10,'s01');
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
   SELECT
     s.name state_name,
     c.name city_name,
     c.population,
     row_number()over(partition by s.name order by c.population desc)rn
   FROM cities AS c 
   LEFT JOIN states AS s
   ON c.state_code = s.code
 )
 select state_name, city_name, population from cte where rn=1
```

Output:

| state_name | city_name | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| state1 | city1 | 100 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0b46ad1027d50539024ee2a3d0a7740d)*